# Ubuntu 14.10 cant find printer option Windows Printer via SAMBA

Tags: printing, samba, 14.10

After upgrading to 14.10 I cant find the option "Windows Printer via SAMBA" on the add new printer dialog.

[image]

The option used to be there in previous Ubuntu versions

Comment: Did the answer work for you? I have smbclient installed and I do get printer via SAMBA, but I can't seem to browse the samba network as I used to. It is grayed out. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I do not know since I enter directly the printer address, I'm currently out of reach of the network so wont be able to test that for a couple of weeks.

Comment: Its okay. I ended up just entering the IP and printer name in the end and it worked out fine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just install the samba client:

```
sudo apt-get install smbclient
```